# Proof that the following function is continuous and (hence holomorphic using Morera's).

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, holomorphic-functions

[image]

How does one go about proving that g is continuous?
I can't seem to find a bound for the integral. Secondly what happens when z is a element of the curve. I know that the function inside the integral is still continuous but I won't be able to split it up to manipulate it.

Any Solutions?(Stuck for 6 hours) I have proven for z in H. Just need a proof for in G

Comment: Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646807/integral-of-a-continuous-function-defined-on-the-trace-of-a-rectifiable-curve).

Comment: the map "$\int _x$" that sends $f\mapsto \int f dx$ is continuous. so you have composition of continuous functions.
$\int_w \circ \phi(_,w) $